# Annotation way: Ignore method call

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a method in java class file like

```
public void SIMPLE_METHOD(some params){
    ...code here...
}
```

Is there annotation I can use above this method so, a method will be ran before SIMPLE_METHOD, if that pre-method returns true this SIMPLE_METHOD will run other wise this method will be ignored and control will be shifted to next execution point.

Comment: boolean flag? any documentation?

Comment: Does it used in testing? JUnit?

Comment: No, its not for unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best way to do something like that in your case (since you're already using spring) is to use Spring AOP and @Around advice.

See [6.2.4.5. Around advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html):

> Around advice runs "around" a matched method execution. It has the
>   opportunity to do work both before and after the method executes, and
>   to determine when, how, and even if, the method actually gets to
>   execute at all.

**UPDATE:** Also, if you need this for implementing cache on method call it might be a good idea to take a look on [Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) and @Cacheable.

Comment: Hi , this is exactly what I am trying to do , is there any example of this